# Adding a javascript bounce effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to add a very subtle bounce effect to the content area, seen in yellow, after clicking the '. Im guessing it would be done in javascript?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UQZGn/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="block">
     <h2>This is green block is fixed</h2>

</div>
<div class="content" id="here">
    <div class="headerbar"> <a href="#here">Top / Reveal</a>
Sublte Bounce
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("a[href='#here']").click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $("body").scrollTop() == 0 ? 300 : 0
    }, "slow");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: so... what exactly is it that you want in addition to what it's already doing?

Comment: If you're including the [jQuery bounce effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/), you can just pass `"bounce"` as the third parameter to `animate`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [easing functions in Jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/effect/#easing). For instance, a [clone of your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UQZGn/1/) using `easeOutBounce`:

```
$("a[href='#here']").click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $("body").scrollTop() == 0 ? 300 : 0
    }, "slow", "easeOutBounce");
    return false;
});
```

**EDIT:** Answering comments, choice of the best easing function is of course subjective, but if you are not happy with any of those provided by Jquery, you can make your own. [Robert Penner's Easing Functions](http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/) is a good list of resources to start exploring, and there's an [example on Forrst.com](http://forrst.com/posts/How_to_create_custom_jQuery_easing_functions-OKb).

Comment: I would've thought `easeOutBack` would be a better choice.

Comment: Is there anyway to tune this so I can define how much it bounces?

Comment: @Rob, See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707605/jquery-ui-easeoutbounce-needs-to-be-more-bouncy)

Answer (score 0):

As @PauloAlmeida says, you should use jQueryUI to add more easing functions.

However, I would suggest animating the `top` property (because it looked like it wasn't working on my computer, because it couldn't scroll that many pixels), and using `easeOutBack` as your animation function.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/UQZGn/2/) is the Fiddle updated as per my suggestion.